# How can a function run when it's not defined until later in the code?

Tags: swift

A beginner's question: here's my code below.

The function `upDateUI()` was not defined using `func upDateUI()` until in the later stage, when I click the button. If the computer is running the code from top to bottom, line by line, why didn't it show an error when it reached the first `upDateUI()`?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//named all outputs
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var falseButton: UIButton!

//created a quiz bank using array
    let quiz = [
        "Four + Two is equal to Six",
        "Five - Three is greater than One",
        "Three + Eight is less than Ten"
    ]

//set the starting value so the LaunchScreen will display Q1 upon running
    var questionNumber = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// but here, upDateUI is not defined until later, upon when I click the button. How can it run here without an error? What is the process of running the code?
        upDateUI()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func answerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        questionNumber += 1
        upDateUI()
    }
    func upDateUI() {
        questionLabel.text = quiz[questionNumber]
    }

}
```

Can someone explain the steps/process of how the code runs?

Comment: The compiler constructs the class by reading the whole file. During actual runtime, your class exists as a complete entity and the "order" of functions is irrelevant. When it gets to a line that calls a function, that function already exists.

Comment: The code doesn't just "run" on its own. It gets *compiled* first. Do you understand what that means?

Comment: Takeaway here is the difference 'Compiling' and 'Runtime'.

Comment: I can't find anything in the [Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language) that specifies that property and function order is irrelevant. Did I miss it or is it an oversight?

Comment: @HangarRash I think the [Access Control](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/accesscontrol) section probably says something to the same effect, even if it doesn't *literally* say that. Namely, the part about the lowest level of access. "Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file". This implies that anything declared in a class at least has to be accessible from the enclosing class.

Comment: Julia, perhaps you come from a programming language, like C, in which functions must be declared before they are used. Swift has no such requirement.

Comment: @Rob oh gosh yes, I started with C! This explains a lot, thanks so much!!

Comment: @Tenfour04 you're right!! I get it now, thanks so much to your help!

Comment: @JuliaWang I rolled back your last edit. Answers should be posted below as an answer instead of editing the question to include the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programming languages like C, we had to declare our functions before we could use them (a practice known as [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)). In Swift, however, there is no such requirement.

In Swift, we do not need forward declarations (nor do we need to write our own header files, the `.h` files of C and Objective-C, to declare the exposed interface). The Swift compiler will automatically resolve functions, properties, etc., regardless of the order that they appear in our source files.

Answer (score 0):

Because "override func viewDidLoad() {..}" is a declaration, which means just put the function on memory, and the codes inside the brackets are not executed until others actually call the function.  In this calls the system calls yourviewcontroller. viewdidload() when the view actually is loaded, meaning all the viewcontroller's functions are also loaded.